# Number a Child Node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to number the child node with the number of times it is present in the xml
for example if a xml looks like this

```
<Orders>
<Date>23-jan-2014</Date>
<Order>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
<Order>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
<Order>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

I need like this

```
<Orders>
<Date>23-jan-2014</Date>
<Order>
<Sq>1</Sq>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
<Order>
<Sq>2</Sq>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
<Order>
<Sq>3</Sq>
<Code>Abc</Code>
</Order>
.
.
.
.

</Orders>
```

Comment: Just to be explicit do you mean -> you need the `Sq` element, to equal the number of times each `Code/text()` is present, in the preceding (including self) `Code` elements? Because thats the behaviour your example shows, but thats not what you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="Orders">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Date"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Order"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Sq><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></Sq>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option that uses `xsl:number` instead of `position()`. [xsl:number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#number) a lot more powerful than `position()` so if your input is more complicated than your example, it may come in handy.

**XML Input**

```
<Orders>
    <Date>23-jan-2014</Date>
    <Order>
        <Code>Abc</Code>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Code>Abc</Code>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Code>Abc</Code>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <Seq><xsl:number/></Seq>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Orders>
   <Date>23-jan-2014</Date>
   <Order>
      <Seq>1</Seq>
      <Code>Abc</Code>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <Seq>2</Seq>
      <Code>Abc</Code>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <Seq>3</Seq>
      <Code>Abc</Code>
   </Order>
</Orders>
```